# DecimalFormat returns " ? " instead of " - " for negative Double input

Tags: java

DecimalFormat returns **?** symbol in place of **-** symbol, when the value given to it, is negative.

*I am using ATOM with SCRIPT package and JDK12.0.2.*

I can replace the " **-** "symbol with virtually any other symbol and the DecimalFormat will give a correct output. This is what makes this issue puzzling to me.  I tried to look into locale issues, but did not manage to resolve the issue.

```
double nTest = -20.20;
System.out.println("simtest " + nTest + "C");

private static DecimalFormat desFor = new DecimalFormat("#0.0;-#0.0");
System.out.println("simtest " + desFor.format(-20.20) + "C");
System.out.println("simtest " + desFor.format(21.45) + "C");

private static DecimalFormat desForAny = new DecimalFormat("#0.0;*#0.0");
System.out.println("simtest " + desForAny.format(-20.20) + "C");
```

> Results

```
simtest -20.2C

simtest ?20,2C  <=== expected  -20,2C

simtest 21,4C

simtest *20,2C
```

Comment: Could this be an encoding issue in your terminal? Is that definitely `-`, as opposed to some unicode symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting `java.util.Locale`

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
DecimalFormat desFor = new DecimalFormat("#0.0;-#0.0", symbols);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I initially had trouble with symbol errors. I am very new to programming, but I managed to figure that I probably needed to import the DFsymbols function. I managed to find the answer from oracle documentation and it is pretty self explanatory.